Events in Azure Storage account
We are planning to migrate one of our applications from Amazon S3 to Azure storage account. As part of this, we have a requirement to automatically move an Azure blob to different folder(archive) when a client download the blob. We were thinking of subscribing to any Blob events which tracks the download event of any blob, but we could not see any such events for a blob. I could see only Blob created, Blob Renamed, Blob deleted events which is not useful for our use case. Is there any other approach to solve this problem?

Please share the code or steps which you have tried so far

Refer this https://davemateer.com/2018/11/07/Azure-Functions-to-Count-Downloads-from-Blob-Storage

There is no direct way to do it.  One way is by using Logs.
Firstly in diagnostic settings , set the logs to go to log analytics. Then you will get logs like below:
StorageBlobLogs
| where OperationName == "GetBlob"


Then create a azure function with http trigger, after that create logic apps, in that you can keep recurrence as the trigger and use Azure monitor connector. From there get the logs. Then whenever a new log is added you can call the azure function http trigger using http connector or Azure functions connector.

then:

After that again set the value with length:

Output:

You can also use array in place of integer variable and then use the latest value of array in condition test. By this way you can get the know whenever blob gets downloaded.
